# Kernel version doesn't update in uname -r (Arch Linux)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, archlinux, uname

After kernel update, the version of kernel in uname is not updated itself.
It is a problem because all the modules are loaded through it, so I had to rename the folder with new modules to the old version (as a temporary solution) but I would like to solve this problem properly.

```
~: pacman -Q linux
linux 4.9.11-1
~: uname -r
4.9.8-1-ARCH
```

Comment: Did you reboot? In any case this question belongs to Super User, UNIX&Linux or other site, Stack Overflow is only for programming questions.

Comment: The `uname` command reads its information form the running kernel, there is nothing to be "updated". Most likely you did install a new kernel, but are still running the old one. Can be even after a reboot, depending on your boot loader setup.

Comment: Reboot doesn't help. I just signed up here and didn't know about that, thank you

Comment: Just check your grub.cfg file, it seems while booting it's not picking the latest kernel.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you replace the kernel image (bzImage or vmlinuz)?. If yes then there is some issue with your grub conf parameter. Otherwise you need to replace the kernel image as well as.

**Below are the steps which you need to update the kernel:**

*1) Replace your kernel image (**vmlinuz or bzImage** you can check the name from your grub conf parameters) with the existing kernel image.*.

*2) Copy the new module folder (containing all new modules) into the **/lib/modules** folder.*.

*3) Sometimes there may be issue during module loading. So you can run the **depmod -a** command inside your new module folder.*

*4) Reboot the board and check the kernel version and your kernel image details (like kernel version and date of compiled kernel image) though **uname -a*** command.*